# Calling props.myFunction() inside a function in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am passing a function to a child component in React and it works perfectly when I call it directly in onClick of a button. But then when I move it into a separate function and call the function from onClick, it no longer works. I can verfity the function is being called with a log statement, but props.myFunction() never gets called. I've encountered this a few times now in React and it always confuses me.

I've looked at some other questions like this one, but its still not helping.

[React: Can't call prop function when it is inside of another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769724/react-cant-call-prop-function-when-it-is-inside-of-another-function)

This code works - it sets loggedIn to true in the parent when the button is clicked

```
export default function SignupModal(props) {
  return (
    <div class="main-block">
      <button
        className="create-account-button"
        href="/"
        onClick={props.setIsLoggedIn(true)}
      >
        Create Account
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this code doesn't set loggedIn to true - but the function still gets called

```
export default function SignupModal(props) {
  const createAccount = () => {
    console.log("this gets logged");

    //but this doesn't get called
    props.setIsLoggedIn(true);
  };

  return (
    <div class="main-block">
      <button
        className="create-account-button"
        href="/"
        onClick={createAccount}
      >
        Create Account
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

can anyone tell me why?

here is what I'm trying to do in the parent, maybe a little unorthodox to render routs like this but it's for a splash page - also as mentioned it works perfectly in onClick()

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

return (
  <>
    {isLoggedIn ? (
      <>
        <SearchBar onLocationChange={onLocationChange}></SearchBar>
        <NavBar></NavBar>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/quik">
            <Pins
              mapRef={mapRef}
              pinnedLocationIds={pinnedLocationIds}
              pinsRemaining={pinsRemaining}
              pushPinnedLocation={pushPinnedLocation}
              usePin={usePin}
              mapCenter={mapCenter}
              setMapCenter={setMapCenter}
              matches={matches}
              setMapZoom={setMapZoom}
              mapZoom={mapZoom}
              changeStatus={changeStatus}
            />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/potentials">
            {/* dont forget, 
            the props for 'Potentials' must also pass 
            through 'potentials in the 'Pins' component! */}

            <Potentials
              pinsRemaining={pinsRemaining}
              matches={matches}
              changeStatus={changeStatus}
            />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/connects">
            <Connects matches={matches} recentMatchId={recentMatchId} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    ) : (
      <Route exact path="/quik">
        <Landing setIsLoggedIn={() => setIsLoggedIn}></Landing>
      </Route>
    )}
  </>
);
```

Comment: What does `setIsLoggedIn` look like in the parent component? My guess is it's a function that returns another function. I'm assuming as much because in the first case you call the function _immediately_ and in the second case you don't call it until inside the click handler.

Comment: its just a setter for a useState variable -- const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false) -- that I'm passing directly

Comment: Can you add the parent component code? Also, do you see what I mean when I say that in the first case you're calling the function immediately whereas in the second state you're passing a function to `onClick`?

Comment: In other words, are you sure it's not setting the parent state to `true` before you even click the button?

Comment: I don't exactly understand how in the first case I'm calling the function immediately because it doesn't actually execute until I press the button.

Comment: I don't think it can be getting set to true immediately because when it's set to true the parent renders a different component, and I can verfiy with dev tools that it isn't set to true. I'll post some more parent code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to demonstrate the difference between your two cases, take this example. When I call a function immediately in the returned JSX code, it fires as soon as the element mounts. However, in the second button, I have to click it before the logging will happen.

```js
function App() {
  return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={console.log("foo")}>Immediate log</button>
    <button onClick={() => console.log("bar")}>Must click to log</button>
  </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

**Edit:** In the case of your code, you're actually setting `setIsLoggedIn` to a function that returns a function when you pass it to your `Landing` component:

```
<Landing setIsLoggedIn={() => setIsLoggedIn} ></Landing>
```

What you want to do instead is this:

```
<Landing setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} ></Landing>
```

Now `setIsLoggedIn` is just a function and your second example will work (your first example will fire immediately and not work how you intend).

Comment: In my case, the log statement in the function is getting called when I click the button, but props.myFunciton() is not. That's what I don't understand, why not? I can see how it could be related to this, but still not understanding. Thanks though

Comment: So you're actually setting `isLoggedIn` to a function that returns a function: `<Landing setIsLoggedIn={() => setIsLoggedIn} ></Landing>` should actually be `<Landing setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} ></Landing>`

Comment: Not sure why on earth I did that. That's progress though, many thanks!